# Pausing the script to comply with Twitter API restrictions

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to get some basic data from a list of Twitter usernames.

```
reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv','rU'))
for row in reader:
    username = row[0]
    try:
        results = api.lookup_users(screen_names = [username])
        for result in results:
            numberoffollowers = result.followers_count
            numberoffriends = result.friends_count
            numberofstatuses = result.statuses_count
            print username, row[1], numberoffollowers, numberoffriends, numberofstatuses, "Completed rows",  row_comp
    except:
            continue
```

This works well, however since API restrictions are 180 calls per 15 minutes I need to restrict the script to that rate (which I don't know how to do). I also don't know how long the pause between 180 calls should be – is it a minute, 15 minutes?

Comment: [`time.sleep(secs)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)?

Answer (score 0):

180 calls per 15 minutes, that's ~1 call every 5 seconds.

```
 import time

 reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv','rU'))
 for row in reader:
     username = row[0]
     try:
         results = api.lookup_users(screen_names = [username])
         for result in results:
             numberoffollowers = result.followers_count
             numberoffriends = result.friends_count
             numberofstatuses = result.statuses_count
             print username, row[1], numberoffollowers, numberoffriends, numberofstatuses, "Completed rows",  row_comp
             # Wait 5 seconds before doing the next lookup
             time.sleep(5)
     except:
         continue
```